# Average Redo Usage Query

Tags: sql, oracle

I'm trying to query the average redo in Gb but failing with the below error.

The query to get redo usage by day & hour (without the `AVG()`) works.

```
SELECT
    Start_Date,
    Start_Time,
    Num_Logs,
    AVG(Round(Num_Logs * (Vl.Bytes / (1024 * 1024 * 1024)),2)) AS AVG_Gbytes,
    Vdb.NAME AS Dbname
FROM
    (SELECT
        To_Char(Vlh.First_Time, 'YYYY-MM-DD') AS Start_Date,
        To_Char(Vlh.First_Time, 'HH24') || ':00' AS Start_Time,
        COUNT(Vlh.Thread#) Num_Logs
    FROM
        V$log_History Vlh
    GROUP BY
        To_Char(Vlh.First_Time,  'YYYY-MM-DD'),
        To_Char(Vlh.First_Time, 'HH24') || ':00'
    ) Log_Hist, V$log Vl , V$database Vdb
WHERE
    Vl.Group# = 1
ORDER BY
    Log_Hist.Start_Date, Log_Hist.Start_Time;
```

The error:

```
ERROR at line 2:
ORA-00937: not a single-group group function
```

Answer (score 1):

In an aggregation query, the `SELECT` columns need to be consistent with the `GROUP BY`.  An aggregation query either has an explicit `GROUP BY` or uses aggregation functions (such as `AVG()`).

In your case, you have an aggregation function, and no `GROUP BY`.  To fix the problem, include all unaggregated expressions in the `GROUP BY`.  So add:

```
GROUP BY Start_Date, Start_Time, Num_Logs, Vdb.NAME
```

It is not clear if this actually does what you *want*.  But you haven't explained.  If this worked (i.e. no error), but doesn't do what you want, ask a *new* question with sample data, desired results, and a clear explanation.